# Add every other pair of cells in column in Google Refine

Tags: csv, openrefine

I've got a data set with the number of men and women in each country in the world.

```
"country","sex","amount"
"Afghanistan","men","number"
"Afghanistan","women","number"
"Albania","men","number"
"Albania","women","number"...
```

I want to add the merge every pair of country rows, and erase the sex column, so that I'd end up with:

```
"country","amount"
"Afghanistan","number"
"Albania","number"
```

How do I add rows together in this way in Google/Open Refine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If the list isn't sorted, sort it on Country and make the source permanent
- Blank down on the Country column
- Remove the Sex column
- Join multivalued cells on the Amount column
- transform Amount column with an expression along the lines of `forEach(value.split(','),a,a.toNumber()).sum()`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I'm curious to know what the `,a,a` part means here?

Comment: You can find the documentation of forEach() in the help for the expression preview dialog.  It takes an array as the first argument, iteratively assigns each value to the variable named in the second argument and then executes the expression in the third argument using that variable, creating an array transformed in some way.  In this case it's transforming an array of strings from the split() into an array of numbers which we then sum.